# How do I reset my network if I don't have a SystemConfiguration folder?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, catalina

I'm currently having a lot of issues with my network, disconnecting often, drive not syncing, sometimes not finding 5GHz networks, certificate approval requests etc, so I wanted to completely reset all my network settings.
I've found three ways to do this:

1. Removing wifi in settings by pressing the minus. This does absolutely nothing I don't even need to reenter my password or anything.
2. Removing all the saved networks from the list. After I press OK and reopen the window all the networks are back in the same spot.
3. Removing some files in the SystemConfiguration folder. When I go to ~/Library/Preferences I don't see the folder. I've tried just adding the folder myself and rebooting to see if any files will appear but they don't.

How do I fix this?
I'm on a 2012 MacBook Pro on catalina 10.15.7

Comment: The network names and passwords are saved in the Keychain.

Comment: If I try to delete through keychain I get "The specified keychain is not a valid keychain file." it says it's a password file tho

Answer (score 1):

The SystemConfiguration folder is in the top (root) level Library folder (`/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration`), not in the User Library folder (`~/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration`).

You may want to be careful about which files you delete, as that may have *consequences*. Make sure you have a backup, and can access the drive from an external, if needs be.

Comment: I've looked in both,  I've also tried searching using terminal but there isn't a folder or file named SystemConfiguration on my filesystem.

Comment: @OK_Rijstkoker There definitely should be: that's where the OS stores info about ... well, the System Configuration, so not having one would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two keychains that store network credentials. I would make a new user on the Mac and verify if your wifi network credentials are in the system keychain or user keychain.

- disable automatic login for this test
- Make a new admin user
- Reboot

If the network connects after a restart and you only log in to the new user account, use keychain access to remove the  network settings from the system keychain.

Repeat the test for the reboot and log in to the old account.

If the password is also in the old user keychain, delete the entry there or repair / [reset the primary user keychain](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/if-you-need-to-update-your-keychain-password-kyca2429/mac).

Once the keychain issue is sorted, you can delete and recreate the network settings and have better results I expect.